# Get the level of a node in a tree using JgraphT

Tags: tree, graph-theory, breadth-first-search, jgrapht

I am using jGraphT data structure , I want to be able to create an ArrayList of a list of objects grouped by their level in the tree.

Here us the graph

```
Graph<Obj, DefaultEdge> serviceGraph =
        new DefaultDirectedGraph<>(DefaultEdge.class);




    serviceGraph.addVertex(a);
    serviceGraph.addVertex(b);
    serviceGraph.addVertex(c);
    serviceGraph.addVertex(d);
    serviceGraph.addVertex(e);
    serviceGraph.addVertex(z);


    serviceGraph.addEdge(a, b);
    serviceGraph.addEdge(b, c);
    serviceGraph.addEdge(b, z);
    serviceGraph.addEdge(b, d);
    serviceGraph.addEdge(d, e);
```

I am able to traverse the graph using a `BFSIterator` as follows

```
A
B
C
Z
D
E
```

Which is the order I want , but I also want to know the level of each node so I can group them as

```
[(A), (B), (C,D,Z) ,(E)]
```

I did not find anything in the `DirectedGraph` API to easily get the level. How do I tag every node with its level as I am traversing the graph in a BFS manner?

Comment: Updated my answer: JGraphT now has a getDepth(V v) method in the BFS iterator. Either download the latest snapshot version from Maven, or wait until the next stable release later this year. Don't forget to upvote.

Comment: The getDepth() method seems to provide the shortest depth.  If you want the longest depth you need another approach.

Answer (score 2):

Edit: these features are now supported in JGraphT. Using the BFS iterator, you can query the depth of a vertex with the `getDepth(V v)` method.

============
Old answer (this is pretty much how it is implemented):

Currently this feature is not available. However, it is being worked on in one of the [Pull Requests](https://github.com/jgrapht/jgrapht/pull/423). It will probably take a few months for this PR to get merged. However, in the mean time, this featured is fairly easy to add. I have implemented a new BFSIterator which is simply a modification of the existing BFSIterator.

```
package org.jgrapht.traverse;

import org.jgrapht.Graph;
import org.jgrapht.Graphs;
import org.jgrapht.graph.DefaultDirectedGraph;
import org.jgrapht.graph.DefaultEdge;

import java.util.ArrayDeque;
import java.util.Deque;

/**
 * A breadth-first iterator for a directed or undirected graph which supports querying the depth of a vertex
 * in the search tree.
 * 
 * <p>
 * For this iterator to work correctly the graph must not be modified during iteration. Currently
 * there are no means to ensure that, nor to fail-fast. The results of such modifications are
 * undefined.
 *
 * @param <V> the graph vertex type
 * @param <E> the graph edge type
 *
 * @author Joris Kinable
 * @since April 21, 2018
 */
public class BreadthFirstIteratorWithLevel<V, E>
    extends CrossComponentIterator<V, E, Integer>
{
    private Deque<V> queue = new ArrayDeque<>();

    /**
     * Creates a new breadth-first iterator for the specified graph.
     *
     * @param g the graph to be iterated.
     */
    public BreadthFirstIteratorWithLevel(Graph<V, E> g)
    {
        this(g, (V) null);
    }

    /**
     * Creates a new breadth-first iterator for the specified graph. Iteration will start at the
     * specified start vertex and will be limited to the connected component that includes that
     * vertex. If the specified start vertex is <code>null</code>, iteration will start at an
     * arbitrary vertex and will not be limited, that is, will be able to traverse all the graph.
     *
     * @param g the graph to be iterated.
     * @param startVertex the vertex iteration to be started.
     */
    public BreadthFirstIteratorWithLevel(Graph<V, E> g, V startVertex)
    {
        super(g, startVertex);
    }

    /**
     * Creates a new breadth-first iterator for the specified graph. Iteration will start at the
     * specified start vertices and will be limited to the connected component that includes those
     * vertices. If the specified start vertices is <code>null</code>, iteration will start at an
     * arbitrary vertex and will not be limited, that is, will be able to traverse all the graph.
     *
     * @param g the graph to be iterated.
     * @param startVertices the vertices iteration to be started.
     */
    public BreadthFirstIteratorWithLevel(Graph<V, E> g, Iterable<V> startVertices)
    {
        super(g, startVertices);
    }

    /**
     * @see CrossComponentIterator#isConnectedComponentExhausted()
     */
    @Override
    protected boolean isConnectedComponentExhausted()
    {
        return queue.isEmpty();
    }

    /**
     * @see CrossComponentIterator#encounterVertex(Object, Object)
     */
    @Override
    protected void encounterVertex(V vertex, E edge)
    {
        int depth= (edge == null ? 0 : getSeenData(Graphs.getOppositeVertex(graph, edge, vertex))+1);
        putSeenData(vertex, depth);
        queue.add(vertex);
    }

    /**
     * @see CrossComponentIterator#encounterVertexAgain(Object, Object)
     */
    @Override
    protected void encounterVertexAgain(V vertex, E edge)
    {
    }

    /**
     * @see CrossComponentIterator#provideNextVertex()
     */
    @Override
    protected V provideNextVertex()
    {
        return queue.removeFirst();
    }

    public int getDepth(V v){
        assert getSeenData(v) != null;
        return getSeenData(v);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Graph<String, DefaultEdge> serviceGraph =
                new DefaultDirectedGraph<>(DefaultEdge.class);
        serviceGraph.addVertex("a");
        serviceGraph.addVertex("b");
        serviceGraph.addVertex("c");
        serviceGraph.addVertex("d");
        serviceGraph.addVertex("e");
        serviceGraph.addVertex("z");


        serviceGraph.addEdge("a", "b");
        serviceGraph.addEdge("b", "c");
        serviceGraph.addEdge("b", "z");
        serviceGraph.addEdge("b", "d");
        serviceGraph.addEdge("d", "e");

        BreadthFirstIteratorWithLevel<String, DefaultEdge> bfs=new BreadthFirstIteratorWithLevel<String, DefaultEdge>(serviceGraph);
        while (bfs.hasNext()) {
            String vertex=bfs.next();
            System.out.println(String.format("Vertex: %s, depth: %s",vertex, bfs.getDepth(vertex)));

        }
    }
}
```

The main function at the bottom executes your example. The output is:

```
Vertex: a, level: 0
Vertex: b, level: 1
Vertex: c, level: 2
Vertex: z, level: 2
Vertex: d, level: 2
Vertex: e, level: 3
```

Obviously you'll have to do a little bit of work to get your array, but that should be straight forward from here. Two remarks:

- This code is not tested beyond your tiny example, so might be bugged
- You can *only* query the depth of a vertex after it has been returned by the iterator.